# how to get data from the entity Repository before every page render in symfony2?

Tags: symfony, service

Q1.I want to count the unread messages before every page rendered ,and add the number into twig template.i don't know how to make it

Q2.i have read the symfony tutorial,it seems that i will make a service ,but i don't know how to do it.is the following code right? and i don't know what to write at the seconde argument

```
namespace App\RepairBundle\Service;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use App\RepairBundle\Entity\RepairMessageRepository;
class CountUnReadMessage
{
    protected $container;
    protected $messageRepository;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container,RepairMessageRepository $messageRepository)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->messageRepository = $messageRepository;
    }

    public function countUnRead()
    {
        $number = $this->messageRepository->countByUnread($this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser()->getId());
        return $number;
    }

}

parameters:
    app.repair.count_unread_message: App\RepairBundle\Service\CountUnReadMessage
services:
    app.repair.count_unread_message:
        class: %app.repair.count_unread_message%
        arguments:
            - @service_container
            - @
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If piece of the twig template containing message counter similar in all templates, you can move it to separate template and call service inside this template. You steps to achieve this might look like this:

1. Write service for getting message counter (you almost got it, but try to avoid injecting whole container in servce since it is a very bad practice. In this case, i think you could inject only `security.token_storage`)
2. Make this service visible in twig templates by declare it in config file.

config.yml

```
twig:
    globals:
        count_read_message: @app.repair.count_unread_message
```

3. In your separate twig file call this service
   message_block.html.twig

   `{{ count_read_message.countUnRead() }}`
4. And include this twig file to needed template (better idea would be keep main template for most of templates and include you file in this template, but this dependenced of template structure)

I hope you got the main idea =)

P.S. Answering for Q2 - it is `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager`

Comment: You might want to clarify how "count_read_message: @app.repair.count_unread_message" will make the service available in all twig templates.  Because I'm pretty sure it does not.  Have you tried it?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html#referencing-services

Comment: Yep.  You might want to edit your answer a bit to show the twig => globals requirement and perhaps include your link.

Comment: Yeah, forgot to add twig.

Comment: And the globals.  Hate to be nit picking but complete information is better than incorrect information.

Comment: thank you very much ,it is helpful ,but when i put {{ count_read_message.countUnRead() }} into twig file there is a error:An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Undefined offset: 0") in @Repair/nav.html.twig at line 18.

Comment: sorry , the error is my Repository's problem.the service works!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inject repository make another service with your repository:

```
app.message_repository:
    class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
    factory: ["@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager", getRepository]
    arguments:
        - App\RepairBundle\Entity\RepairMessage
```

Then in your service:

```
app.repair.count_unread_message:
    class: %app.repair.count_unread_message%
    arguments:
        - @service_container
        - @app.message_repository
```

BTW you don't need container, inject only `security.token_storage` instead of `container`.

Comment: thank you very much ,your advice is very helpful ,but when i get the service in the twig file ,there is a errer:An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Undefined offset: 0") in @Repair/nav.html.twig at line 18.  can you help me ag?

Comment: the error is my Repository's problem.the service works!! thank you !